# Need keep open Dialog of Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem because I want to keep a Dialog of Primefaces open, but every time I press the register button, it closes.

This, when the data is well loaded, would not be a big problem. Since they are recorded in the database and the operation ends.

My intention is to make the Dialog remain on the screen until I decide to close it with another button. This is because if the validations throw an error, it should remain until they correct the data, or decide not to register.

Attached Dialog code:

```
           <h:form id="frmAltaCombustible">
                <p:dialog header="Nuevo Combustible" widgetVar="dialogoNuevoCombustible" resizable="false" width="900" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode" >
                    <p:panelGrid id="nuevoCombustible" columns="3">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Identificador de Combustible:" for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:inputText id="txtIdentificador" label="Identificador" value="#{mbCombustibles.combustible.idcombustible}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validadorVacio"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="txtIdentificador"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Nombre de combustible:" for="txtDescripcion"/>
                        <p:inputText id="txtDescripcion" label="Nombre" value="#{mbCombustibles.combustible.descripcion}">
                            <f:validator validatorId="validadorVacio"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="txtDescripcion"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Registrar Combustible" actionListener="#{mbCombustibles.registrar()}" update=":frmAltaCombustible,:frmListaCombustibles"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
```

Comment: Then just don't update the full form that contains the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is update the form fields within the dialog you should use `update="nuevoCombustible"` instead.

Assuming that your dialog is rendered by changing the CSS attributes with javascript, you're effectively losing those values when the component is re-rendered.

Comment: This works perfect.
But I forgot to tell you that Dialog instantiated it from a button that is in a datatable, and does not update it in this way.

Sorry for the forgetfulness.